# How can I check if a user already exist in mongoDB?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I am creating an account creation system with express.js but I would like to know how I can find out if the user already has an account (with his email) on my DB in order not to register him twice.

```js
const router = require("express").Router(),
    User = require("../database/models/User.model.js");

const cryptoJS = require("crypto-js");

//REGISTER
router.post("/register", async (req, res) => {
    const { username, email, password } = req.body;

    if (User.findOne({ email: email })) {
        return res.status(400).json({
            message: "This email is alredy existing in our database" 
       });
    } else {
        const user = new User({
            username: username,
            email: email,
            password: cryptoJS.AES.encrypt(
                password,
                process.env.CRYPTO_KEY
            )
        });
        await user.save()
            .catch(err => res.status(500).json({ error: err.message }));
    }
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: This question has been answered several times before. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44687044/node-js-check-if-user-exists

Comment: Ok sorry I may have looked wrong

Comment: Also, you will need  a response with status 200, when the new user is created.

Comment: Instead of encrypting the password (with a static encryption key), you should better store a hash-value of it.

Answer (score 2):

```
const router = require("express").Router(),
const User=require("../database/models/User.model.js");

const cryptoJS = require("crypto-js");

//REGISTER
router.post("/register", async (req, res) => {
    const { username, email, password } = req.body;
    const checkUser = await User.findOne({ email: email })

    if (checkUser) {
        return res.status(400).json({
            message: "This email is alredy existing in our database" 
       });
    } else {
        const user = new User({
            username: username,
            email: email,
            password: cryptoJS.AES.encrypt(
                password,
                process.env.CRYPTO_KEY
            )
        });
        await user.save()
            .then(data=>res.json(data))
            .catch(err => res.status(500).json({ error: err.message }));
    }
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: I've already tried to do this but it always returns the fact that the user exists even if it doesn't

Comment: I have cahnges some part of code try again please